# iOS Swift UITableView tableFooterView Auto Size

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout, tablefooterview

I want to add a footer to my table which will have a varying height based on the message etc.  I use auto layout and have the label configured to work wrap and have the number of lines set to 0.  You can see the template cell in my tableView below as well as all the constraints for the label and button.  You can also see the properties set for the label that do make it wrap across multiple lines.  The challenge is that when the footer is displayed, the height of the footer is not auto sizing to show all the content.

[image: Interface Builder Info]

Here is the code I use to add the template cell as the footer.

```
        let  FooterCell = NearbyPlacesTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(lc_MessageCellTableIdentifier) as! NearbyPlacesMessageCell
        FooterCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        FooterCell.SetMessage(true)
        FooterCell.layoutIfNeeded()
        NearbyPlacesTable.tableFooterView = FooterCell
```

The set message function simply puts the message text in the label.  This is working correctly as you can see from the screen shot.

Any idea how to make it so my entire footer is visible?

So I am updating the question hoping someone will see it and be able to answer the question.  Can anyone provide information on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Is your tableFooterView a Cell? Why not UIView?

Comment: Cell is a UIView isn't it?  I can downcast a Cell to UIView.  What different could a UIView make versus a cell?

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to your label? `lblMessage. preferredMaxLayoutWidth = lblMessage.bounds.size.width`

Comment: Bannings - The issue is that the footer are is not long enough so I am a little confused as to why I would set properties for the width to fix that.

Comment: I think that if you never set the label's preferredMaxLayoutWidth so the intrinsicContentSize of the label will not be what you're expecting.